# How to use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in twapi, a package in tcl?

Tags: windows, tcl, tk-toolkit

I wish to know how twapi functions can be used to query "display name" in windows.
::twapi::comobj is API to access com objects.
Thanking you.

Comment: You mean display name like the one you get from `$env(USERNAME)`?

Comment: Any reason not to use [tcom](http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/) for working with COM objects from Tcl? It's designed for that.

Comment: For me tcom and twapi is same because both access com objects, But I do not know how access "Fullname". Whereas $::env(USERNAME) is not sufficient for my case, instead to retrieve full-name.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
twapi::get_user_account_info YOURNAME -full_name
```

and see if that gives you what you need. I'm not sure that will give you what you need in an Active Directory environment but worth a short.

Otherwise, you will have to find a VBScript fragment that uses COM to access Active Directory accounts and translate that to tcom or twapi. Should not be too hard.

Comment: It is giving error "Could not retrieve global user or group information:  The user name could not be found." Is "YOURNAME" means username?